# Kong: pass user credentials to service

Tags: microservices, credentials, kong

Using [kong](https://getkong.org/), it is straightforward to [secure services using authentication](https://docs.konghq.com/getting-started-guide/2.3.x/secure-services/).
Kong provides several plugins to do the job, such as [basic authentication](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/basic-auth/), [key authentication](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/key-auth/), [HMAC authentication](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/hmac-auth/), [OAuth 2](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/oauth2/), etc.

Once authorized, how client's credentials (such as user name) can be passed to the service?

Just passing the request headers to the services, implies that the services need to change the way they fetch the client's credentials, if Kong's authentication mechanism changes. This is something I'd rather avoid.

Plugins are available to perform transformations on the requests, such as [request transformer](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-transformer/). This may leave the capability to implement any custom policy to pass credentials.

I wonder if any somehow "standardized" mechanism is already available.

Comment: The header of the request forwarded to the service still contains the authorization information. For basic authentication, you can easily extract the username from it. For OAuth2, it will contain an access token. Usually, the access token contains username, full name, roles etc. If it's an opaque access token, the service can use the access token to request the Id Token from the OAuth 2 service with all the user details.

Comment: @Codo: sure, but that would imply to change the service's policy to fetch user's credentials, if the authentication mechanism changes. I'll update the question, pointing out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all authentication plugins add some X-Consumer-* upstream headers, so these can be used by the services to gather the required information.

References:

- https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/oauth2/#upstream-headers
- https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/ldap-auth/#upstream-headers
- https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/basic-auth/#upstream-headers
- https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/key-auth-enc/#upstream-headers
- https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/hmac-auth/#upstream-headers
- ...